# How to Activate Zswap Successfully for Matlab Computation in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: boot, grub2, 16.04, kernel, matlab

Condition: to activate `zswap` module in Ubuntu 16.04 successfully for Matlab/.... computation
Relevant part in `/etc/default/grub`

```
...
zswap.enabled=1              # NB only change here 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" 
                             # NB also tried to have the line here unsuccessfully    
...
```

I try to activate `zswap` and run `sudo update-grub`

```
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
/etc/default/grub: line 12: zswap.enabled=1: command not found
```

I also tried the code where `zswap` line is after `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` unsuccessfully.

### My current setting after heynnema's answer

- Have the following in `/etc/default/grub`, which works unspecifically; `dmesg | grep zswaps` returns something

  ```
  # https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zswap
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash zswap.enabled=1 zswap.max_pool_percent=25 zswap.compressor=lzo"
  ```
- Run `sudo update-grub`.

### Its effect on the maximum Ram?

There are some threads about it is saving some pages in the pool, etc [zswap: How to determine whether it is compressing swap pages?](https://lkml.org/lkml/2013/7/17/147)  However, there is no studies about its effect on the maximum Ram for the computaion.

System: Linux Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
Linux kernel: 4.6
Linux kernel options: wl
Matlab: 2016a
Hardware: Macbook Air 2013-mid
Related threads: [How can I enable zswap?](https://askubuntu.com/q/361320/25388), [Zswap Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zswap), [zswap: How to determine whether it is compressing swap pages?](https://lkml.org/lkml/2013/7/17/147)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You put your `zswap.enabled` in the wrong place.

Change this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
zswap.enabled=1
```

To this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash zswap.enabled=1"
```

then `sudo update-grub` and `reboot`.

If it doesn't work, it may not be available/compatible with 16.04.

Comment: How can you show that this activates `zswap`? The command `lsmod | grep zswap` gives blank. Command `swapon` also does not show anything about `zswap`.

Comment: Command `dmesg | grep zswap` gives `[    2.867664] zswap: loaded using pool lzo/zbud` once. However, it does not tell me what is the effect of `zswap`. Can you evaluate its effect better?

Comment: Google "zswap" to understand more about how it works. I just wanted to tell you how to enable it correctly. I've never used it. Cheers, Al

Comment: @Masi this page on zswap is excellent https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zswap