# Increasing usable RAM with an external harddrive

Tags: ram, external-hdd

I am trying to run a simulation and need more RAM for a big array. I'm at about 24 GB and need about 100 GB.

I have an external hard drive with 2 TB of memory, so is there a way I can use this to increase my current RAM? I am not too good in Ubuntu and know how to do this with Windows, and am hoping someone can help (or at least tell me yes I can do this.). Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Increase Ubuntu's Virtual Memory and/or Swap for Matlab?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799834/how-to-increase-ubuntus-virtual-memory-and-or-swap-for-matlab)

Comment: While you _can_ use an external drive for swap, that will be very slow.

Comment: If you can, use a SSD drive instead.

Comment: NVMe or Intel Optane should be good. External HDD will give you <250 Mb/s, you should know this before the start.