# EverSpace 2 crash due to OOM

Tags: graphics, games, 23.04

I am a relatively new user and I am trying to troubleshoot my Everspace install. After about 30 minutes of play, Everspace crashes. My dmesg log reads as follows:

```
    [ 1192.925982] [   4766]  1000  4766    52023    10117   409600        0           200 apt-check
[ 1192.925984] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/org.gnome.Shell@wayland.service,task=RSG-Linux-Shipp,pid=4644,uid=1000
[ 1192.926065] Out of memory: Killed process 4644 (RSG-Linux-Shipp) total-vm:9695404kB, anon-rss:3881560kB, file-rss:448kB, shmem-rss:128kB, UID:1000 pgtables:16948kB oom_score_adj:100
[ 1194.072896] rfkill: input handler enabled
[ 1194.951973] kauditd_printk_skb: 6 callbacks suppressed
[ 1194.951976] audit: type=1400 audit(1702657465.534:162): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/snap/snapd/20290/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=4866 comm="snap-confine" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
[ 1194.951981] audit: type=1400 audit(1702657465.534:163): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/snap/snapd/20290/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=4866 comm="snap-confine" capability=38  capname="perfmon"
[ 1195.649519] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
[ 1195.802107] rfkill: input handler disabled
[ 1204.153520] rfkill: input handler enabled
[ 1205.055782] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
[ 1205.381611] rfkill: input handler disabled
[ 1206.403436] audit: type=1107 audit(1702657476.987:164): pid=625 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.8" pid=5910 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=636 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[ 1206.403826] audit: type=1107 audit(1702657476.987:165): pid=625 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.8" pid=5910 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=636 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[ 1206.406283] audit: type=1107 audit(1702657476.987:166): pid=625 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.8" pid=5910 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=636 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[ 1206.406597] audit: type=1107 audit(1702657476.987:167): pid=625 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.8" pid=5910 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=636 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[ 1206.720225] audit: type=1400 audit(1702657477.303:168): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/etc/appstream.conf" pid=5910 comm="snap-store" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[ 1210.416153] audit: type=1326 audit(1702657480.999:169): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=2 subj=snap.opera.opera pid=6742 comm="opera" exe="/snap/opera/279/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=330 compat=0 ip=0x7fb469f4d4e7 code=0x50000
[ 1210.416321] audit: type=1326 audit(1702657480.999:170): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=2 subj=snap.opera.opera pid=6741 comm="opera" exe="/snap/opera/279/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=330 compat=0 ip=0x7f6bd435d4e7 code=0x50000
[ 1212.157575] audit: type=1107 audit(1702657482.739:171): pid=625 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=6489 label="snap.opera.opera" peer_pid=623 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
```

My initial research said that systemd-oomd is that culprit, so I killed it:

```
sudo systemctl status systemd-oomd
○ systemd-oomd.service
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit systemd-oomd.service is masked.)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

Here are my system details:

```
System:
  Host: geary-Aspire-A315-59 Kernel: 6.2.0-39-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: GNOME v: 44.3 Distro: Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Acer product: Aspire A315-59 v: V1.22
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: ADL model: Callisto_ADU v: V1.22 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: Insyde v: 1.22 date: 05/31/2023
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 21.7 Wh (54.5%) condition: 39.8/39.9 Wh (99.8%)
    volts: 11.4 min: 11.6
CPU:
  Info: 10-core (2-mt/8-st) model: 12th Gen Intel Core i5-1235U bits: 64
    type: MST AMCP cache: L2: 6.5 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 2500 min/max: 400/4400:3300 cores: 1: 2500 2: 2500
    3: 2500 4: 2500 5: 2500 6: 2500 7: 2500 8: 2500 9: 2500 10: 2500 11: 2500
    12: 2500
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake-UP3 GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: Quanta ACER HD User Facing type: USB driver: N/A
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.8 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.8
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: X: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa
    dri: iris gpu: i915 resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~23.04.1 renderer: Mesa Intel
    Graphics (ADL GT2)
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio
    driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
  Sound API: ALSA v: k6.2.0-39-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-1: PipeWire v: 0.3.65 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: MEDIATEK driver: N/A
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter type: USB
    driver: r8188eu
  IF: wlx40ed001396e7 state: up mac: 40:ed:00:13:96:e7
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: IMC Networks Wireless_Device type: USB driver: btusb
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 2 state: down
    bt-service: enabled,running rfk-block: hardware: no software: no
    address: 00:00:00:00:00:00
RAID:
  Hardware-1: Intel Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller driver: vmd
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 238.47 GiB used: 65.13 GiB (27.3%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Kingston model: OM8SEP4256Q-AA size: 238.47 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 86.21 GiB used: 65.07 GiB (75.5%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p5
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 256 MiB used: 65.2 MiB (25.5%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 52.8 MiB (2.6%) file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 45.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Info:
  Processes: 325 Uptime: 34m Memory: 7.46 GiB used: 2.54 GiB (34.0%)
  Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.25
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I will be sure to post back should I discover the culprit. My current theory is that I really am running out of memory, thus why it dies. When it crashes, it takes GNOME with it, forcing the UI to restart and I have to log back in. I keep turning my graphical options down and it doesn't seem to help. I am now out of my league.

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188024/how-to-test-oom-killer-from-command-line) help?

Comment: How much memory do you have?

Comment: @Raffles Thank you! And yes it does

Comment: @vidarlo I have 8 GB

Comment: And the game consumes 9GB. You need more memory...

Comment: @vidarlo You are correct. See my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either it's a memory management bug in your program, or you need swap space.

One uses swap space to control what happens when programs allocate all the real memory, and want more. After all releasable cache (some cached blocks are "in use", and cannot be freed) has been released, the system enters the Out-Of-Memory state. In the Out-Of-Memory condition, with swap, some task's memory is written to disk, freed for reuse, and later  returned to memory (swapped in) when the task runs. Without swap, the system may freeze,  the dreaded OOM-Killer (a pseudo process, hard-coded in the kernel) runs, and picks a process to KILL, in order to free memory. The OOM-Killer is known for inconvenient choices.

System hibernation requires a RAM-sized, contiguous swap area.

Read `man mkswap fallocate  filefrag swapon fstab`.

If adding swap space simply delays the onset of the problem, it's a bug. Report it to the game developers.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I followed the advice and researched the links and man pages provided. I found this lovely program called Swapspace that creates dynamic swap files. A part of my set up that I didn't mention is that I'm dual booting, so I have all this HDD space just hanging out over on my Windows side. So I installed swapspace with:
`sudo apt install swapspace` , mounted the drive, and ran `sudo swapspace -s /media/geary/Acer`

Tada! No more crashes and the performance is great. Onequick note to anyone using this in the future: I am using this on a SDD, which is a big no no because SDD's don't have quite as many read-writes as a traditional platter drive. Since I only have one HDD, I'm putting this poor thing through a lot just to play a game. I'm aware of this and I'm fine with it, but anyone else should way this decision for themselves. I'll have to teach myself how to set this up to run all the time next, but this issue is solved.